# Gradle Project Dependencies - As Shared Projects or JAR's?

Tags: groovy, gradle, build.gradle

So basically we have a project structure like below:

```
 C:\Projects\Eclipse\Workspace->
         afbEJB
         rmcEJB
         rmbEJB
         **bridgesClient**
         **sharedApp**
         **framework**
         **commonApp**
```

The ones marked in bold are standard java projects which are dependencies for the first 3 EJB projects. These standard projects are not built as JAR'rather actual projects so I am guessing in order to build EJB projects I would have to use ':Project' syntax.

Questions:

1. I was not able to refer to the standard projects without first creating **settings.gradle** file.
2. I had to create build.gradle file in all of the standard projects as well as the EJB projects. Why is there a mandate for creating gradle files in dependent projects as well? Cant the root project build it when it finds the project dependencies as part of the dependencies {...} ? that way there would be less number of build.gradle files in the entire workspace.

I think a better way around this would be to create JAR's for the standard projects and refer them as **compile fileTree(dir: 'dir-where-jar-are-stored')**?

What do you guys think?

Thanks,
Yogendra

Answer (score 0):

ad 1) Yes, a `settings.gradle` is required for multi-project builds.

ad 2) It isn't necessary to create multiple build scripts. If you prefer, you can configure all projects from a single build script. Often, a mixture of these styles is used (configure commonalities from root script, remainder from subproject scripts).

ad 3) In general, I wouldn't turn the projects into separate builds, as this would complicate matters for build users. In particular, they'd have to execute multiple builds, and in the right order.

To learn more about multi-project builds, check out the "multi-project builds" chapter in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html), and the many sample builds in the full Gradle distribution.

Comment: Peter, I am not able to understand your point 2, can you elaborate with an example if possible?

Comment: Please see the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) and/or have a look at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/build.gradle.